# Add UISearchBar fix on top of a View in iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a `UIViewController` and want to add a `UISearchBar` fix at the top like here:

[image]

When I tap into the search bar I want it to look like this:

[image]

It should be displayed over the navigation bar.

**How can I do this using InterfaceBuilder or in Code instead of a Storyboard?**

Answer (score 1):

If you are building for iOS 8 you can use a `UISearchController`, if you are building for anything below iOS 8 you will have to use the now deprecated `UISearchDisplayController`.

[Apple Documentation - UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html)

[Apple Documentation - UISearchDisplayController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do all of that via the Interface Builder but if you change your mind and decide to use code, insert this in viewDidLoad() after declaring `var resultSearchController = UISearchController()` globally:

```
self.resultSearchController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
            self.definesPresentationContext = true
            return controller
        })()
```

This will do exactly what you want for iOS 8 and above.

Update:
For interface builder, drag a UITableViewController and embed it in a Navigation Controller (select it, Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller). Set the Navigation Controller as the initial view controller. Next drag in a Search Bar and Search Display Controller into the TableView Controller inside the table view positioning it at the top of the table view. There you go

Comment: @confile make it a UISearchDisplayController instead of a UISearchController in the code. IB instructions stay the same. Do you need help with the scope buttons as well?

Comment: Yes I need help with the scope buttons as well.

Comment: With interface builder I only have a table view. In the interface builder when I create a UITableViewController. I cannot drag a Searchbar onto a table view.

Comment: How do I get the external Cancel button and how can I change its text?

Comment: @confile after adding the search bar, click on it and go to Attributes Inspector and click on 'Show Cancel Button' and 'Show Scope Bar'. Underneath that click the + button to add the scope titles

Comment: I cannot add a SearchBar to a TableView in InterfaceBuilder.

Comment: @confile make sure it's a Table View Controller not  Table View

Comment: When I use InterfaceBuilder I have only a TableView when I create a new file with xib of type UITableViewController.